# How to represent method calls ReScript 9.1.2

Tags: interop, ffi, rescript

ReScript 9.1.2 made the original `@meth` semantics inaccessible they said to use `@send` external instead to represent method calls

My questions are:

can `@send` external be inside a type?
and is this a correct way to use it knowing that it generates the same javascript code?

**Using @meth:**

```ml
@meth
"createElement": string => Web_node.t,

let createElement = typ => document["createElement"](typ
```

**Using @send external:**

```ml
@send external
createElement: (t,string) => Web_node.t="createElement"

let createElement = typ => createElement(document, typ)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "inside a type", but yes, that is how you represent a method call. You can verify this by looking at the generated JavaScript. An easy way to do this is by creating an example in the [rescript playground](https://rescript-lang.org/try), which will show that it generates this:

```ml
function createElement(typ) {
  return document.createElement(typ);
}
```

Another handy resource is the [rescript bindings cookbook](https://github.com/rescriptbr/rescript-bindings-cookbook).

Comment: inside a type record

example: 

type _xmlhttprequest ={@send external...}

yes I am trying the code in the playkground I just wanted to confirm that it is the right way to do it.

Thanks for the resource I will check it

Comment: In that sense, no you cannot put it inside a type. `external`s are toplevel definitions, more like function definitions than type definitions, but where the function body is "external".

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, appreciate the help